# How to access output parameter value

Tags: java, jna

It's the first time I need to use JNA, I've read something about it and there are still some stuff not very clear for me...

Well, I need to use a .dll from a third party. They provided me their library .h file.

```
/*
 * Biblioteca de Automação Comercial
 *
 * API para facilitar integração com CTF Client
 */

/*prevent multiple includes*/
#ifndef _H_AUTTAR_BIBLIOTECA_AC_CTF
#define _H_AUTTAR_BIBLIOTECA_AC_CTF

/*useful definitions*/
#ifndef BOOL
  #define BOOL int
#endif

#ifndef TRUE
  #define TRUE 1
#endif

#ifndef FALSE
  #define FALSE 0
#endif

#ifndef NULL
  #ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL 0
  #else
    #define NULL ((void *)0)
  #endif
#endif

/*OS specific*/
#ifdef _WIN32
  #define CTF_API  __stdcall
#else
  #define CTF_API  
#endif

/*make this code usable by C++*/
#ifdef __cplusplus 
  extern "C" {
#endif

/*API function calls*/
void CTF_API iniciaClientCTF(char* resultado,   /* out */
                             char* terminal,    /* in */
                             char* versao_ac,   /* in */
                             char* nome_ac,     /* in */
                             char* num_sites,   /* in */
                             char* lista_ips,   /* in */
                             char* criptografia,/* in */
                             char* log,         /* in */
                             char* interativo,  /* in */
                             char* parametros   /* in */
                             );

void CTF_API iniciaTransacaoCTF(char* resultado, /* out */
                                char* operacao,  /* in */
                                char* valor,     /* in */ 
                                char* num_doc,   /* in */ 
                                char* data_cli,  /* in */ 
                                char* num_trans  /* in */ 
                                );

void CTF_API iniciaTransacaoCTFext(char* resultado,  /* out */
                                   char* operacao,   /* in */
                                   char* valor,      /* in */
                                   char* num_doc,    /* in */
                                   char* data_cli,   /* in */
                                   char* num_trans,  /* in */
                                   char* dados);     /* in */

void CTF_API continuaTransacaoCTF(char* resultado, /* out */
                                  char* comando,   /* in/out */
                                  char* num_sc,    /* in/out */
                                  char* p_sc,      /* in/out */
                                  char* tam_sc,    /* in/out */
                                  char* aux);      /* in/out */

void CTF_API finalizaTransacaoCTF(char* resultado, /* out */
                                  char* confirmar, /* in */
                                  char* num_trans, /* in */
                                  char* data_cli );/* in */

/*make this code usable by C++*/
#ifdef __cplusplus 
    }
#endif

/*end of multiple-include prevention*/
#endif
```

My mapping interface is

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface ICTFClient extends Library {

    ICTFClient INSTANCE = (ICTFClient) Native.loadLibrary("ctfclient", 
ICTFClient.class);

    public void iniciaClientCTF(byte[] resultado, 
                            byte[] terminal, 
                            byte[] versao_ac, 
                            byte[] nome_ac,
                            byte[] num_sites, 
                            byte[] lista_ips, 
                            byte[] criptografia, 
                            byte[] log, 
                            byte[] interativo,
                            byte[] parametros);

    public void iniciaTransacaoCTF(byte[]  resultado, 
                                byte[]  operacao, 
                                byte[]  valor, 
                                byte[]  num_doc,
                                byte[]  data_cli, 
                                byte[]  num_trans);

    public void iniciaTransacaoCTFext(byte[]  resultado, 
                                byte[]  operacao, 
                                byte[]  valor, 
                                byte[]  num_doc,
                                byte[]  data_cli, 
                                byte[]  num_trans,
                                byte[] dados);

    public void continuaTransacaoCTF(byte[]  resultado, 
                                byte[]  comando, 
                                byte[]  num_sc, 
                                byte[]  p_sc,
                                byte[]  tam_sc, 
                                byte[]  aux);


    public void finalizaTransacaoCTF(byte[]  resultado, 
                                byte[]  confirmar, 
                                byte[]  numTrans, 
                                byte[]  dataTransacao);
}
```

My question is: How can I access the output parameter returned by the library?
Do you think my interface mapping is correct?

Comment: If the API just writes the output into the pointer passed to it, just make sure you create a large enough array and then pass it to the function. The array will contain the data. Have you tried it?

Comment: I doing something like  byte[] outParameter = "00".getBytes(); then I call the library passing it....then I guess I can retrive with Native.toString(outputParameterPassedBefore)...   Is that it?

Comment: If the function really only writes two bytes, then yeah. Read the library's documentation to find how many bytes the functions require (i.e. `byte[] out = new byte[4096];`. If all of the `char*` in-params are strings, just use a Java `String` - JNA will work with it. As for the out param, `char[]` would be easiest but `byte[]` might be safer in case you know the encoding.

Comment: Err, except after the function has written the data to your *Java* `byte[]`, you can just use `String`'s constructor to turn the bytes to a string.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was in doubt because a support guy(functional not development) from the third party library passed me a code that didn't worked....as I am new to JNA I trusted him....I was in a hurry...he told me to pass a hard coded string as output parameter in some of the library's function...he supplied me with the mapping interface.....as I could not have the result I wanted from the library I started to study a little about JNA but I still felt some insecure about some points...Thanks

Comment: Working with native libraries from a higher level environment definitely has its challenges! I'll post an answer with the key points from my comment, if you find a different solution which answers your question, be sure to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "out" argument usually means that the function will write to the pointer provided to it. The function doesn't seem to take the output buffer's size as an argument, so you'll need to read the library's documentation to find out how big of a buffer the output needs (how many bytes).

```
byte[] outputBuf = new byte[4096]; // Change 4096 to the correct size
ICTFClient.INSTANCE.iniciaClientCTF(outputBuf, /* ... */);

// If the output is not ASCII, e.g. encoded in an encoding which supports Portugese characters, 
// pass the correct CharSet instead
String output = new String(outputBuf, StandarsCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println("Output: " + output);
```

By the way, if all of the `char*` in-params are strings, just use a Java `String` - JNA will work with it.